# Segmentation fault instead of showing message - reading from a file by using pointers in c

Tags: c, arrays, pointers, coredump

I wrote a program, which reads from a file. I use a condition in which I print that the array is too big, but when I use a too big array instead of showing this message I have segmentation fault.

This is my program

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

#define N 10000 // Maximum array size

int _strlen(char *array) {
    int i;
    for (i = 0; array[i] != '\0'; ++i);    
    return i;
}

int readText(FILE *wp, char *s, int max) {
    int sum = 0;
    if (_strlen(s) > max) {
        printf("This array is too big. Maximum size is %d", max);
    } else {
        while ((*s++ = fgetc(wp)) != EOF) {
            sum++;
        }
        *(s-1) = '\0';
    }
    return sum;
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    FILE *wz, *wc;                       
    char *s;
    char array[N];
    s = array;
    if (argc != 3) {                              
        printf("Wrong arguments number\n");
        printf("I should run this way:\n");
        printf("%s source result\n",argv[0]);
        exit(1);
    }

    if ((wz = fopen(argv[1], "r")) == NULL) {
        printf("Open error %s\n", argv[1]);
        exit(1);
    }
    if ((wc = fopen(argv[2], "w")) == NULL) {
        printf("Open error %s\n", argv[2]);
        exit(2);
    }

    fprintf(wc, "Read text from file source.txt");

    readText(wz, s, 10000);   

    return 0;
}
```

In output I want to have: `This array is too big. Maximum size is %d`
Instead of `Segmentation fault core dumped`

In addition, I want to say that the program is when I use a smaller array, but I want to show the user a proper message when he uses too big array instead of segmentation fault.

Thanks, I change my program in that way. The only problem is that this program check the if condition in every while loop so this program could be slow.

```
int readText(FILE *wp, char *s, int max) {
    int sum = 0;
    if (_strlen(s) > max) {
        printf("This array is too big. Maximum size is %d", max);
    } else {
        while ((*s++ = fgetc(wp)) != EOF) {
            sum++;
            if (sum > max) {
                printf("This array is too big. Maximum size is %d", max);
                break;
            }
        }
        *(s-1) = '\0';
    }
    return sum;
}
```

Comment: Consider putting the array on the heap (instead of the stack). There's limited stack space and this may be causing your issue. You can do this by doing `char *array = calloc(sizeof(char), N);`

Comment: You have some undefined behavior.  Array is never assigned a value so the value of strlen(s) is undefined.

Comment: You are passing a pointer to uninitialized data (`s`) to `readText`, so how do you expect the call to `_strlen(s)` in that function to work?

Comment: Thanks, I edited my post and write new function it works. The only problem is that this program chech the if condition in every while loop so this program could be slow.

Comment: Get rid of the call to `_strlen` in `readText`. The `_strlen` function tells you how long a string you already have is, not how big a buffer that a string could be stored in is. You need a string to call `_strlen` and you don't have one in the beginning of `readText` because you haven't read it yet.

Comment: @Mark: you can accept one of the answers by clicking on the grey checkmark below its score.

Answer (score 2):

The remarks / other answer solve your undefined behavior (segmentation fault in your case).

> The only problem is that this program check the if condition in every while loop so this program could be slow.

Your program is not slow because of a 'if' but because you read the file char per char.

Using *stat* or equivalent function you can get the size of the file to read it throw only one *fread* :

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>

#define N 10000 // Maximum array size

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
  char array[N];
  FILE *wz, *wc;                       
  struct stat st;
  off_t sz;

  if (argc != 3) {                              
    printf("Wrong arguments number\n"
           "I should run this way:\n"
           "%s source result\n", argv[0]);
    exit(1);
  }

  if ((wz = fopen(argv[1], "r")) == NULL) {
    printf("Cannot open %s to read : %s\n", argv[1], strerror(errno));
    exit(1);
  }

  if (stat(argv[1], &st) == -1) {
    printf("Cannot get stat of %s : %s\n", argv[1], strerror(errno));
    exit(1);
  }

  if (st.st_size > N-1) {
    printf("This array is too big. Maximum size is %d", N-1);
    sz = N-1;
  }
  else
    sz = st.st_size;

  if (fread(array, 1, sz, wz) != sz)  {
    printf("cannot read %s : %s", argv[1], strerror(errno));
    fclose(wz); /* for valgrind end test etc */
    exit(1);
  }
  array[sz] = 0;
  fclose(wz);

  if ((wc = fopen(argv[2], "w")) == NULL) {
    printf("Cannot open %s to write : %s\n", argv[2], strerror(errno));
    fclose(wz); /* for valgrind end test etc */
    exit(2);
  }

  /* ... */

  fclose(wc);

  return 0;
}
```

Knowing the size of the file allows to remove that limitation to a constant size and try to read the file while you can allocate enough memory for :

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
  char * array;
  FILE *wz, *wc;                       
  struct stat st;

  if (argc != 3) {                              
    printf("Wrong arguments number\n"
           "I should run this way:\n"
           "%s source result\n", argv[0]);
    exit(1);
  }

  if ((wz = fopen(argv[1], "r")) == NULL) {
    printf("Cannot open %s to read : %s\n", argv[1], strerror(errno));
    exit(1);
  }

  if (stat(argv[1], &st) == -1) {
    printf("Cannot get stat of %s : %s\n", argv[1], strerror(errno));
    exit(2);
  }

  if ((array = malloc(st.st_size + 1)) == NULL) {
    printf("Not enough memory to memorize the file %s\n", argv[1]);
    exit(3);
  }

  if (fread(array, 1, st.st_size, wz) != st.st_size)  {
    printf("cannot read %s : %s", argv[1], strerror(errno));
    fclose(wz); /* for valgrind end test etc */
    free(array); /* for valgrind etc */
    exit(4);
  }
  array[st.st_size] = 0;
  fclose(wz);

  if ((wc = fopen(argv[2], "w")) == NULL) {
    printf("Cannot open %s to write : %s\n", argv[2], strerror(errno));
    free(array); /* for valgrind etc */
    exit(5);
  }

  /* ... */

  fclose(wc);
  free(array); /* for valgrind etc */

  return 0;
}
```

Anyway because of the usage of the program "source result" may be you want to copy the file specified by *argv[1]* in the file specified by *argv[2]*, in that case better to read and write block by block rather than to read all to not use a lot of memory for nothing and to manage the case the input file size is greater than the memory size.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot *measure* the length of the destination array with `_strlen(s)`, the size is given as an argument and reading an uninitialized array with `_strlen()` has undefined behavior.

Furthermore, you store `fgetc(fp)` to `*s++` before testing for `EOF`. This is incorrect in all cases:

- if `char` type is signed, `EOF` cannot be distinguished from a valid byte value of `\377`.
- if `char` is unsigned, `EOF` cannot be tested because it has been converted as a `char` value of `0xff`, hence the loop runs forever, writing beyond the end of the destination array until this causes a crash.

You simply want to add a test in the reading loop to stop reading bytes from the file when the buffer is full and read the bytes into an `int` variable so you can test for end of file reliably.

Here is a modified version:

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

#define N 10000 // Maximum array size

int readText(FILE *wp, char *s, int max) {
    int i = 0, c;
    while (i < max - 1 && (c = fgetc(wp)) != EOF) {
        s[i++] = c;
    }
    s[i] = '\0';
    return i;
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    FILE *wz, *wc;                       
    char array[N];
    int nread;

    if (argc != 3) {                              
        printf("Wrong arguments number\n");
        printf("I should run this way:\n");
        printf("%s source result\n", argv[0]);
        exit(1);
    }

    if ((wz = fopen(argv[1], "r")) == NULL) {
        printf("Open error %s\n", argv[1]);
        exit(1);
    }
    if ((wc = fopen(argv[2], "w")) == NULL) {
        printf("Open error %s\n", argv[2]);
        exit(2);
    }

    fprintf(wc, "Read text from file source.txt\n");

    nread = readText(wz, array, N);   

    printf("Read %d bytes\n", nread);

    return 0;
}
```